# php sign up facebook, twitter and google + without duplicate accounts

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-plus

i'm building a website where you can signup with facebook - twitter or google plus 
and i wondered if there is something that connects these three social network sites ( common id ) so i can have only 1 database row for each person not 3 database rows
something like when i try to login with facebook and i have signed up with google plus it logins with the same data without submitting a new row database for facebook
which means i need to find a common factor which i can use in logging in 
thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed field that will be shared between the three. You have two possible ways to handle this situation:

1) Use something like an email address, which you can get for all three, and hope they use the same address.

2) After they log into the account using one of them, let them link additional accounts themselves with the other two. (Or even let them link additional accounts from the same service multiple times.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this library to get info from providers: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/
After getting info from providers, you get an unique identifier for connected provider.
That way - you can use that identifier as a provider column for some specific user in your system.

E.x. you could have a table with:
userId, userEmail, ..., twitterIdentifier, googleIdentifier, facebookIdentifier

and when a user first connects with any provider, you can create a new user in your db with correct provider field populated.
On login, you check the correct column for requested provider, and know which user it is...

Answer (score 0):

Then check with the user id in the table and update the twitter\Google\fb authos fields with in the same row using the uid as a updateble argument. The related oauth ids are useful to the user login time

Comment: i dont get it, how can i find out that this is the same person